# Obtain $z_1,z_2$ and $z_1/z_2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $j = \sqrt{-1}$

$z_1 = 5 \left(\dfrac{\cos 126^\circ{} + j \sin 126^\circ{}}{\cos 72^\circ{} + j \sin 72^\circ{}}\right);$

$z_2 = 2\cos 30^\circ{} + j \sin 30^\circ{};$

Find using algebraic calculations $z_1\cdot z_2$ and $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$.

It is advised to use the exponential form to have fewer calculations. The problem is that $2\cos(30^\circ{})$. It is not a mistake in fact the $r_2$ is given in the results as $\left(\frac{\sqrt {13}}{2}\right)$ so the $2$ is actually only multiplying $\cos x.$

Comment: z1 = 5 *(cos 126° + j sin 126°) / (cos 72° + j sin 72°);

r2 = sqrt(13)/2

sorry for not posting the correct way the math formule

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Your question seems a bit confusing. is $j$ mean to be $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: You can, and you should, post your formulas using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), otherwise they are unreadable.

Comment: Does $j={}{}i$?

Comment: yes  $j = i = \sqrt(-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint ($i=\sqrt {-1}$):
$$
z_1=5\frac{e^{\frac{7\pi} {10}i}}{e^{\frac{4\pi} {10}i}}=5e^{\frac{3\pi} {10}i};\quad
z_2=r_2e^{i\phi_2},
$$
where
$$
r_2=\frac {\sqrt {13}}2;\quad\phi_2=\arctan\frac1 {2\sqrt3}.
$$

> Explaination: the general transformation of complex numbers to polar representation reads:
>   $$
> x+iy=\operatorname{sign}(x)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan\frac yx}
> $$

Comment: $r_2$ is given in the results of the exercise, therefore I cannot just assume it as known and use it to reverse the process. What I would like to understand is, given that the usual formula for writing a complex is $r(cosx + i sinx)$, how is it possible to have in this case  $(a*cosx + i sinx)$?

Comment: I have added an explanation.